# Insert before and after case insensitive string find

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a string in another string and insert text before and after each time it is found in a way that is case insensitive.

I have come up with the following, which works, it just feels less than ideal so I was wondering if anyone had a more efficient approach.

```
import re

test_string = "My name is Jon not jon."

search = re.compile(re.escape('jon'), re.IGNORECASE)

find = re.findall(search, test_string)

for found in find:
    test_string = test_string.replace(found, '<span>%s</span>' % found)

print test_string

"My name is <span>Jon</span> not <span>jon</span>"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is is what `re.sub` is for:

```
>>> re.sub('(?i)(jon)', r'<span>\1</span>', s)
'My name is <span>Jon</span> not <span>jon</span>.'
```

(Note I've used the `(?i)` instead of `re.I` (but, no difference between the two), and captured the group, which is the `\1` for the replacement string)

On another note: you may wish to consider using word boundaries or similar so that you only actually replace the word "jon", not say "jonathan", or such like - depending on requirements.

Comment: Jon answering a question containing 'jon'. :P

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
test_string = "My name is Jon not jon."
output = re.sub('([jJ]on)',r'<span>\1</span>', test_string)
print output
```

Output:

```
My name is <span>Jon</span> not <span>jon</span>.
```

If you want to filter more wisely your regex match, better to put a `space` before and after `[Jj]on` like `( [Jj]on )`. So it will match only the word `jon`.

```
output = re.sub('( [jJ]on )',r'<span>\1</span>', test_string)
```

OR 
**Edit:**
as @Jon Clements suggested, you can use word boundaries instead of space.